# If $f(x)$ is discontinuous at 0, does that mean $f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)}$ is also discontinuous?

Tags: limits, continuity

If $f(x)$ is discontinuous at 0, does that mean $f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)}$ is also discontinuous?

I know that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both discontinuous at 0, that does not necessarily mean that $f(x) + g(x)$ is discontinuous at 0, (take $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x) = x - \frac{1}{x}$), but I cannot think of an example to show $f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)}$ is continuous even if $f(x)$ is discontinuous.

Does this mean that it is impossible?

Comment: It might be interesting that the answer is different if you consider $f - 1/f $ (assuming $f>0$) instead of $f + 1/f $.

Comment: Actually, $x\to1/x$ is not discontinuous at $0$, it is **undefined**. This function happens to be continuous everywhere on its domain of definition. Common mistake.

Answer (score 11):

Consider the function:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}2 &\text{ if }x\ne0\\\frac12&\text{ if }x=0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider
$$
f (x) = \begin {cases} 2 , &\text{ if } x \in \Bbb {Q},\\
1/2, &\text { if } x \notin \Bbb {Q}.
\end {cases}
$$
Then $f + 1/f \equiv 5/2$ is continuous,  but $f $ is not.

Comment: Yes, but 5/2 not 3/2

Comment: @almagest: Whoops. Of course. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow complex-valued functions, it is easy to show that the answer is no: consider
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} i & x\leq 0 \\ -i & x > 0 \end{cases} $$
Obviously $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0$. However, if $x \leq 0$,
$$ f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)} = i+\frac{1}{i} = 0, $$
and similarly, $ -i+1/(-i)=0$. Hence
$$ f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)} = 0 $$
for any real $x$, which is obviously continuous.